# paypal live error de inicio de sesión

Tags: java, android, paypal

He terminado una app, hice  las pruebas con sandbox y todo bien, al momento de cambiar a ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION no tuve problemas, pero al iniciar sesión me dice error de inicio de sesión.

He verificado las credenciales de usuario y las de desarrollador  en paypal live y todo esta bien, Mi cuenta es de argentina y estan deshabilitadas las 3 ultimas opciones de paypal live.

Direct credit cards Accept payments from customers directly using their credit cards on your web or mobile app.

Future Payments Use virtual tokens to save customer payment information.

Payouts Payout up to 500 recipients in one API Call.

**En la consola veo este mensaje**

```
E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"error":"invalid_user","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}
E/PayPalService: invalid_user
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button pay;
private static final String CONFIG = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "AS28yU-cXWZuh-vVJ1TJUvWcdF4HpywXmBv2STQw4PeFSgC91hCt9UkC7tViiTMbAXs-pij14AFDjUhB";


private static final int REQUEST_PAYMENT    = 1;


private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()

                          .environment(CONFIG)
                          .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                          .merchantName("MultiAndroid zone")
                          .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/privacy"))
                          .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/legal"));


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     pay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

     pay.setOnClickListener(this);

     Intent intent = new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
     intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
     startService(intent);


     }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch (v.getId()){


    case R.id.button1:

        PayPalPayment item = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(1), "USD", "MultiAndroid zone",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

          Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PaymentActivity.class);

           in.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,item);

           startActivityForResult(in, REQUEST_PAYMENT);

           break;


        }

    }



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      if (requestCode == REQUEST_PAYMENT){


          if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){


     PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

      if(confirm== null){

           try {

               System.out.println("Responses" +confirm) ;

               Log.i("PayPal Example Payments" , confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(confirm.toJSONObject().toString());


               String paymentID=obj.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
               System.out.println("payment id:-=="+paymentID);

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), paymentID ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


               }catch(JSONException e){

               Log.e("Payment", "failure occured:",e);
           }
      }

          }else if(requestCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){



              Log.i("Paymentdemo","The user cancelled");


         }else if(requestCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID){

             Log.i("paymentdemo","Invalid payment Submitted");


         }


      }

      }}
```

dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.5')
}
```

Comment: @joseNaava! estas usando el password default? 11111111

Comment: no utilizo el normal de paypal, ya he provado con sandbox y todo funciona bien. tambien he provado con 11111111 y nada noc si sea un problema con android.

Comment: Si estas probando en el SandBox reinicia tu password y asegura el usuario correcto, el error especifica "usuario invalido".

Comment: Utilize SandBox para test la app y funciona 100% en sandbox que es el entorno de pruebas. pero al cambiar a live dinero real. PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION; me arroja el mensaje usuario invalido

Answer (score 2):

Por el mensaje de error creo que tu implementación es correcta ya que obtuviste tu Client Id, pero el problema simplemente deben ser las credenciales:

> E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server
>   response:{"error":"invalid_user","error_description":"Invalid user
>   credentials"}

Seguramente tus credenciales son incorrectas, recuerda que el password default es:

```
 "11111111"
```

si no recuerdas te sugiero [reinicies las credenciales, **aquí un tutorial.**](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1497&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]